# A technical problem with the server created an error. Error in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, error

I am getting the below error, when I try to insert an image in a CMS page.

> A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to
>   continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again
>   later.

How to resolve it?

There are two kind of error which i am getting.
Initially https://prnt.sc/qisky9 and after I click on `Browse` I get https://prnt.sc/qisl30

Comment: Please check-in the log file.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh nothing comes in log file related to this

Comment: Send me path where you add it?

Comment: I am trying to Insert image in a CMS page from backend

Comment: Have able to select an image from browse?

Comment: No. When i click on browse and select image then i get File validation error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102828/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-nafisa).